# Can phosphorescence have higher energy than fluorescence?

Tags: optics, energy, visible-light, fluorescence

Our teacher has posed a question:

"
A 450nm photon is absorbed and two things can occur:

- Fluorescence at 600nm
- Phosphorescence at 500nm

Is it possible to prove the above values? If not give an assumption of what could have happened based on the Jablonski diagram provided. (The measurements are correct)
[image: fig 1]
"

As far as I have understood due to the triplet state the energy loss will cause emission at a longer wavelength. I have tried to come up with an explanation based on vibrational relaxation but that has lead me nowhere?

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our teacher gave us the answer.

"Someone mixed up the two measurements"
Duh...